when the input is same , then why is the output different?
let number2=prompt(" specify enter").trim();  // input= "25"
let number1="25";

console.log(Number(number2)) // output= NAN [NOT A NUMBER]
console.log(Number(number1)) // output= 25`

I have already asked chatgpt and chatgpt also agrees with me that if the input you entered is a string "25" , then  the output should be same . the output should be :
25
25

What are you entering into the prompt? If I enter 25 I get 25 as an output, not NaN

Do not put  25 . put "25" .

when you enter 25 , it is a number . but when you enter "25" , it is string_number

It's not, a string is a string and a number is a number. But javascript coerces values into certain types for certain operations. If you need this to not happen, JS might not be right for you.

Wait, are you typing, literally, "25"? Because that is never a number due to the " character being used inside the string. (Don't forget that " and ' are just as valid a character as any other, otherwise you couldn't write them out on Stack Overflow!)

25 is a number (integer) data type.
It represents a numerical value without any decimal places.
"25" is a string data type. It represents a sequence of characters, in this case, the digits "2" and "5" enclosed in double quotes

in variable number1 , i have literally stored "25" , and it is giving output 25 . but when i store literally "25" in variable number2 , it is giving output NAN .

The equivalent would be if you did number1 = "\"25\"". The initial " quote is part of the syntax for creating string, not the string's contents. When you put "25" into the prompt your string's contents will also contain escaped quotes "

i didnt understand . explain more clearly

i have declared "25" as a string in varaible number1 .then i am trying to convert it into a number . and it is showing output 25 which is ok   . NOW when when prompt asks me , i give him  input "25" but when i convert it into a number , it should aslo give output 25 as above did but instead , it is giving input NAN

We can't see what you're typing, but as mentioned, don't literally type out the quotes.

@hafizUmer Anything you enter into the prompt window will result in a string already, if you enter abc, then the resulting value in the number2 variable will be the string abc. If you enter 25 then the result of number2 will be a string (if you created this as a literal, it would be written as "25"). By putting quotes into the prompt, you'll be creating a string that has quotation marks within it. You would need to remove/handle the additional quotation marks from your string's content to convert it correctly, or just enter it as 25 without the quotes.

@hafizUmer There is no such thing as integer in JavaScript. All numbers are doubles.

@NickParsons you are the man bro ! now i totaaly understand what are you trying to say . thanks once again

prompt returns a string
You get NaN if you enter "25" with quotes since you will be trying to parse "\"25"\"


let number2 = prompt(" specify enter").trim(); // input= "25" - prompt ONLY returns a string
let number1="25"; // this is a valid number in a sttring
console.log(JSON.stringify(number2), Number(number2)) // output= NAN [NOT A NUMBER] because you are trying to parse "\"25"\"
console.log(JSON.stringify(number1), Number(number1)) // output= 25 because you are parsing "25"




You are treating a string like a number.
you could make sure that your string is a number before performing any Number specific operations on it.
shortest solution: console.log(+number2)
The plus sign converts your string to a number.
